# iOS 8 Launch Screen Lifecycle Event

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, launch-screen

Is there an event that is triggered or a function that is called when the launch screen is about to removed for the main storyboard? I want to animate a transition between the two (which I can do on the main storyboard but would prefer to do it on the launch screen).

Comment: `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: I put a breakpoint in this method and the simulator did not have the launch screen showing

Comment: You can't rely on the state of the UI when you put a breakpoint in this method, but this method is the first opportunity you have to affect what is on screen after the launch image is shown.

Comment: So Is it the correct place to put code that executes right before the launch screen view is removed? Otherwise the transition animation won't work.